# After Placing Order, Customer Does Not Redirect to “Order Placed Successfully” and is Returned to Cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have create a magento website, in this when we place order of an item then,
    **strong text**After Placing Order, Customer Does Not Redirect to “Order Placed Successfully” and is Returned to Cart.

Order also gone in magento admin section under "Sales > order".
    I have tried check/money order, authorize.net etc for order place but no positive results found,
    under this they also not checked correct payment details for order in authorize.net.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is problem related with Payment method.

You can check this using other Payment method like Cash on Delivery etc.

Also please make sure you are entering correct information for Address like ZIP Code etc.

Comment: I have checked place order process different payment methods but no positive results found for me. so i think it is not a payment method problems, please give me some other solution for this problem if you have..... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you list what extensions you have installed for your Magento install?

I've experienced this problem before when I had a custom module that observes the checkout event, when something has gone wrong with the code itself.

Chances are either one of your extensions or a custom built module that's listening to the checkout events is causing the problem.

Comment: I have install AW_SARP and Advanced_Newsletter Extension for our magento website

Comment: @kapil-gupta I'd recommend you try disabling the extensions one at a time (flush cache afterwards) and see if either of the extensions are causing the issue. I suspect it's the AW_SARP one since it sounds like it'd have observers for checkout events.